# TreeViewItem expaning like a chain-event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

In my WPF application, if I open one of the treeviewitems to display all the child items, it goes on a chain event and slowly starts opening all the parent items. For example if I opened the Red, it'd slowly open the blue's until they are all open;

[image]
My TreeView Code;

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvTagList" Margin="15, 40, 15, 50" SelectedItemChanged="tvTagList_SelectedTagChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ExtryzeAccentBrushSecondary}" BorderThickness="2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Foreground="White"
                                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type  DataBind:TagClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TagClassMagic}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataBind:TagEntry}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TagFileName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

My classes;

```
public class TagClass
{
    public string TagClassMagic { get; set; }
    public ITagClass RawClass { get; set; }
    public List<TagEntry> TagEntries = new List<TagEntry>();

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new CompositeCollection()
                {
                    new CollectionContainer() { Collection = TagEntries }
                };
        }
    }

}
public class TagEntry
{
    public string TagFileName { get; set; }
    public ITagEntry RawTag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the code in your SelectedItemChanged="tvTagList_SelectedTagChanged"?  Could you be possibly doing something in there that would be causing the sibling nodes to open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we had to change;

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

to

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `Children` every time returns a new `CompositeCollection` which is propably expanded by default. Try returning `TagEntries` directly or return a new `CompositeCollection` at first time only.